# YouTube (and other media) stutters when safari isn't focused

Tags: macos, safari

I have this weird issue that has been plaguing me for ever even across multiple fresh MacOS installed and machines. I just cant get to the bottom of this and need help.

when I play media in safari (YouTube,vimeo etc) and move focus to any there app that's not safari the playback becomes super choppy and stutters like crazy.

Does anyone have a clue on why this happens or how to approach debugging this?

im on 12.5.1 using a MacBook Pro (14-inch, 2021), M1 Max, 32 GB RAM, though it happened with other machines and previous macOS versions. The CPU is never close to full load and so is the RAM.

Comment: We don't have enough detail… What Mac, what OS, what else is running at the time, how busy is the CPU, how many displays & what resolution?

Comment: thx! updated post @Tetsujin

Comment: anyone? really struggling with this